# Regex matches non-english letters as non-word characters

Tags: ruby, regex

```
@raw_array[i]=~/[\W]/
```

Very simple regexp. 
When I try it with some non-latin letters (russian to be specific) condition is false.

What can I do with this?

Comment: Try using `^\pL` instead of `\W`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@raw_array[i] =~ /[\p{L}]/
```

Tested with Cyrillic characters.

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop

Answer (score 2):

From the [Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html):

> `/\W/` - A non-word character (`[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

It's specifically not Unicode-aware.  Perhaps something like this will work better for you:

```
@raw_array[i]=~/[^[:word:]]/
```

Comment: That's the point. \W is unfortunately not Unicode aware. So you need to use the unfortunately more obscure Unicode character classes. But do not that Cyrillic is NOT Unicode. Unicode is an several sets of encodings that include Cyrillic. Cyrillic is also encoded in forms like KOI-8 which font use the same bytes.

Comment: @JoeHalfFace I'm not sure what you're not understanding -- your question was about why the `\W` character class considered some non-latin letters to be non-word characters.  I explained that that character class is not Unicode-aware; it has a very narrow definition of what constitutes a "word" character, as documented above. I then showed you a Unicode-aware character class which works more or less how you hoped `\W` would.

Comment: About Unicode I got you wrong, but in irb: `?> 'ываыва'=~/[[:word:]]/
=> nil`

Comment: @JoeHalfFace That's weird; irb returns `0` for that on my machine.

Comment: Something very strange... `>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"`. But as I can check in Rubular, ruby acts like lower than 1.9 . I can't figure out what is going on...